# Having issues with matching the PaypalAPI criteria for payments

Tags: c#, .net, model-view-controller, paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

Im using the PaypalApi for my online shop.

In order to send a payment through the API, your Subtotal Amount + tax + shipping must be equal to the totalAmount of the order and Paypal is restricted to only 2 decimals. My problem is that sometimes some values become 3 decimals  and when i try to format it to two decimals my calculations end up being wrong. No matter how i twist and turn im ending up with a method that is not equal to the TotalAmount.

Here is the code for the paymentMethod.

```
  private Payment ExecutePayment(APIContext apiContext, string payerId, string paymentId)
    {
        var paymentExecution = new PaymentExecution() { payer_id = payerId };
        this.payment = new Payment() { id = paymentId };
        return this.payment.Execute(apiContext, paymentExecution);
    }

    private Payment CreatePayment(APIContext apiContext, string redirectUrl)
    {

        //similar to credit card create itemlist and add item objects to it

        var countryParams = LanguageService.GetUiCultureByCountryPrefix(Country);
        var productsInPaypalCart = (List<Dictionary<string, object>>)Session["ProductsInPaypalCart"];
        double subtotalAmount = 0;
        double unitPrice = 0;
        double taxedUnitPrice = 0;
        var itemList = new ItemList() { items = new List<PayPal.Api.Item>() };
        double shipping = 0;
        double totalAmount = 0;
        double taxedAmount = 0;
        double taxInTwoDecimails = 0;
        double subtotalAmountInTwoDecimals = 0;
        foreach (var product in productsInPaypalCart)
        {

            var dbProduct = Service.ProductService.GetProduct(int.Parse(product["reference"].ToString()), Country);

            shipping = dbProduct != null && dbProduct.ShippingFee.HasValue && shipping < dbProduct.ShippingFee ? dbProduct.ShippingFee.Value : shipping;

            unitPrice = (int)product["unit_price"] / 100;
            taxedUnitPrice = (unitPrice  * 0.875);

            itemList.items.Add(new PayPal.Api.Item()
            {

                name = (string)product["name"],
                currency = countryParams.Currency,
                price = (taxedUnitPrice).ToString("F").Replace(",", "."),
                quantity = Convert.ToString(product["quantity"]),

            }


            );

            subtotalAmount += (taxedUnitPrice * (int)product["quantity"]);
            totalAmount += (unitPrice * (int)product["quantity"]);
            taxedAmount += ((totalAmount * 0.125) + shipping * 0.25);

        }
        var b = Math.Round((decimal)subtotalAmount, 2);
        subtotalAmountInTwoDecimals += Convert.ToDouble(b);
        var a = Math.Round((decimal)taxedAmount, 2);
        taxInTwoDecimails += Convert.ToDouble(a);


        var payer = new Payer() { payment_method = "paypal" };

        // Configure Redirect Urls here with RedirectUrls object
        var redirUrls = new RedirectUrls()
        {
            cancel_url = redirectUrl,
            return_url = redirectUrl
        };

        // similar as we did for credit card, do here and create details object
        var details = new Details()
        {
            tax = ((totalAmount * 0.125) + shipping * 0.25).ToString("F").Replace(",", "."),
            shipping = (shipping * 0.75).ToString("F").Replace(",", "."),
            subtotal = (subtotalAmount).ToString("F").Replace(",", ".")
        };

        // similar as we did for credit card, do here and create amount object
        var amount = new Amount()
        {
            currency = countryParams.Currency,
            total = ((subtotalAmount + taxInTwoDecimails)  + (shipping * 0.75)).ToString("F").Replace(",", "."), // Total must be equal to sum of shipping, tax and subtotal.
            details = details
        };

        var transactionList = new List<Transaction>();

        transactionList.Add(new Transaction()
        {
            description = "Transaction description.",
            invoice_number = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
            amount = amount,
            item_list = itemList
        });

        this.payment = new Payment()
        {
            intent = "order",
            payer = payer,
            transactions = transactionList,
            redirect_urls = redirUrls
        };

        // Create a payment using a APIContext

        return this.payment.Create(apiContext);

    }
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are figuring "total amount" and the sum of "subtotal + tax + shipping" separately. Why not first ensure subtotal, tax, and shipping are only figured to 2 decimal places, and then add them together and send *that* as the total amount? IE do everything in 2 decimal points

Comment: Can you give me an example of it, im not seeing how i am figuring them out sepraetly..